# Validating Word Add-in, can't seem to access schemas.microsoft.com?

Tags: xml, validation, ms-word, ms-office, office-js

I'm working on an add-in for Word, and I'm trying to get it up and running, but I'm getting some XML schema validation errors that I have to fix first.
The problem is, the links that I'm being given in the error messages just directs me to a plain page with the message "[The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.](http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides)"

As far as I can tell, the entirety of "schemas.microsoft.com" is currently broken and I'm not sure how else to fix the errors without being able to read through it. Anyone have any ideas on how I can proceed?

Not sure it'll be helpful, but just in case, here's the errors that it's spitting out, as well as the manifest file itself.

Errors:

```
Calling validation service. This might take a moment...
-------------------------------------
Validation: Failed

Error #1:
XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests. (link: https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation)
  - Details: The element 'Icon' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Image' in namespace 'https://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0'. List of possible elements expected: 'Image' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0'.
  - Line: 87
  - Column: 20

Error #2:
XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests. (link: https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation)
  - Details: The element 'Icon' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Image' in namespace 'https://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0'. List of possible elements expected: 'Image' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0'.
  - Line: 102
  - Column: 22

Error #3:
XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests. (link: https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation)
  - Details: The element 'Resources' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Images' in namespace 'https://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0'. List of possible elements expected: 'Images, Urls, ShortStrings, LongStrings' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0'.
  - Line: 123
  - Column: 8
-------------------------------------
```

I have no idea why it's saying 'Image' is an invalid child element when it lists 'Image' as the only valid element.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:bt="https://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
    xmlns:ov="https://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
    xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">


  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>452435-24352345-23452345-141324</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>0.9.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Example Pty. Ltd.</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Example App" />
  <Description DefaultValue="This is an example app"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://example.com/assets/icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://example.com/assets/icon-80.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <!--<SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]">-->

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <!--Begin TaskPane Mode integration. This section is used if there are no VersionOverrides or if the Office client version does not support add-in commands. -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://example.com/index.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <!-- End TaskPane Mode integration.  -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <!-- Begin Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- The Hosts node is required. -->
    <Hosts>
      <!-- Each host can have a different set of commands. -->
      <!-- Excel host is Workbook, Word host is Document, and PowerPoint host is Presentation. -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest. -->
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
          <GetStarted>
            <!-- Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
            <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>

            <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
            <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>

            <!-- Point to a url resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <!-- Function file is a HTML page that includes the JavaScript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called.
            Think of the FunctionFile as the code behind ExecuteFunction. -->
          <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />

          <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!-- Ensure you provide a unique id for the group. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name. -->
              <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
                <!-- Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                <!-- Icons. Required sizes 16,32,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX. -->
                <!-- Use PNG icons. All URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS. -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>

                <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                  </Icon>

                  <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <!-- You can use resources across hosts and form factors. -->
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://example.com/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://example.com/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://example.com/assets/icon-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://example.com/index.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://example.com/function-file/function-file.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <!-- ShortStrings max characters==125. -->
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Group1Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <!-- LongStrings max characters==250. -->
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
  <!-- End Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->

</OfficeApp>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your manifest. I'm making inquiries with the Microsoft engineers. In the meantime, are you seeing the error in Visual Studio? If not, where do you see it?

Comment: This is cross posted on the Word Answers Community forum.

Comment: @RickKirkham I'm not using VS, I'm on a Mac and I've written the whole thing in sublime. I'm seeing the errors when I run npm run validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix,
Just needed to change 
`xmlns:bt="https://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"`

to

`xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"`